# iPhone Backup in External Storage

Tags: iphone, backup

I have been doing iPhone backup in external hard drive for quite sometime. This helps me to save lot of hard disk space of my Macbook. I connect iPhone via USB cable to my MacBook and open iPhone sync window in Finder. When I click Back Up Now or Sync button, the data in iPhone will do backup to my external SSD instead of MacBook local storage.

https://www.imore.com/how-move-your-iphone-or-ipad-backups-external-hard-drive

But later I realised that I may not be able to restore backup if I follow this practice of doing backup to external storage. Restore backup button remains disabled now in Sync window in Finder because there is no local backup for iPhone. Can someone help me to know how to restore backup of iPhone from external storage?

Answer (score 0):

When you back up your iPhone to your MacBook, backups are usually stored in `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/`. Locating the backups on the external drive and copying the one you want to restore to this location should make it restorable. See also: [Locate backups of your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204215).

If there is not enough space available on your Macbook so you can't copy the backup over, or if you want a less-effort solution that you can use to easily backup and restore using an external drive, you can use a *symlink* to *map* a folder on your external drive to the above path. See this article for instructions: [How to Back Up Your iPhone to a Different Location on Your Mac](https://www.makeuseof.com/back-up-iphone-to-different-location-on-mac/).